# Line break in the mailto onclick

Tags: javascript, mailto, line-breaks

The code below works great except the email has all the text on one line like this: 
Height: 60 | Diagonal: 123 | Width: 107 | Total SF: 13.92 | Cost Per SF: 450 | Total Cost: $6,264.00

I would like to break after each so it looks like this:

> Height: 60
>   Diagonal: 123
>   Width: 107
>   Total SF: 13.92
>   Cost Per SF: 450
>   Total Cost: $6,264.00

I tried \n \r \n\r etc but none of them work. Any ideas?

```
<a class="emailText" href="mailto:?subject=Screen Dimensions" onclick="this.href='mailto:?subject=Screen Dimensions&body='+'Height: '+document.forms.myform.high.value+' | '+'Diagonal: '+document.forms.myform.diagonal.value+' | '+'Width: '+document.forms.myform.wide.value+' | '+'Total SF: '+document.forms.myform.sf.value+' | '+'Cost Per SF: '+document.forms.myform.csf.value+' | '+'Total Cost: '+document.forms.myform.tc.value">Email</a>
```

Comment: If you are testing on Windows, `\r`, `\n` and `\n\r` will not work.  The correct combination is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to use the ASCII values for line feed/carriage return:

```
%0A = \n

%0D = \r

%0D%0A = \r\n
```

Works like a charm.

```
<a href="mailto:person@somedomain.com?subject=My subject&body=Hello %0D%0A World">Link</a>
```

(Spaces added around %0D%0A for clarity.  In reality, this could add unwanted white space.)

Comment: Your great man I would spend all day looking for it. I love this site.

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that doing so strips off the email signature in Outlook?

Answer (score -2):

try using `<br/>` as a line break

Comment: You won't be able to use HTML inside mailto-Links.